# Oracle sequence is not getting called in Hibernate One to Many

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jpa

I am working on simple one to many relationship in Hibernate JPA. Below are table details. One request can have more than one attachment.

```
CREATE TABLE "SCOTT"."AW_MEDIA_REQUEST" 
   (    "ID" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "REQUESTOR_NAME" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE), 
    "REQUESTOR_TYPE" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE), 
     CONSTRAINT "AW_MEDIA_REQUEST_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("ID")
    )

    CREATE TABLE "SCOTT"."AW_ATTACHMENT" 
       (    "ATTACHMENT_ID" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
        "ATTACHMENT_NAME" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
        "REQUEST_ID" NUMBER, 
         CONSTRAINT "AW_ATTACHMENT_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("ATTACHMENT_ID")
    )

CREATE SEQUENCE  "SCOTT"."JINESH_SEQ"  MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1 CACHE 20 NOORDER  NOCYCLE ;
```

Below are the class mapping details for the above table.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "AW_MEDIA_REQUEST")
public class MediaRequestDetails {
    
    
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="media_request_seq")
    @SequenceGenerator(
        name="media_request_seq",
        sequenceName="MEDIA_REQ_SEQ",
        allocationSize=1
    )
    @Column(name = "ID")
    Long requestId;
    @Column(name = "REQUESTOR_NAME")
    String requestorName;
    @Column(name = "REQUESTOR_TYPE")
    String requestorType;
    
    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL,fetch=FetchType.LAZY,mappedBy="mediaRequDetails")
    Set<AttachmentDetails> attachmentDetail;

//getters and setters are here
}
```

Below is the class mapped with the AW_ATTACHMENT table.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "AW_ATTACHMENT")
public class AttachmentDetails {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="attch_seq")
    @SequenceGenerator(
        name="attch_seq",
        sequenceName="JINESH_SEQ",
        allocationSize=1
    )
    @Column(name = "ATTACHMENT_ID")
    Long attachmentId;
    @Column(name = "ATTACHMENT_NAME")
    String attachmentName;
    
    
    @JoinColumn(name = "REQUEST_ID")
    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL,optional=false)
    @MapsId
    private MediaRequestDetails mediaRequDetails;

    //getter and setter methods are here
}
```

Below is the class I am using to save the MediaRequestDetail with the corresponding Attachment details.

```
public class TestAttachmentSample {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
        EntityManagerFactory emFact=Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("rawsjpa");
        EntityManager entityManager = emFact.createEntityManager();
        if(entityManager!=null){
            System.out.println("************* EntityManager is obtained *****************");
        }
        
        MediaRequestDetails obj=createMediaRequestDetails();
        createAttachmentDetails(obj);
        saveAttachmentDetails(obj,entityManager);
        
        //createOnlyAttachmentDetails(entityManager);
        
        emFact.close();
    }

    private static void saveAttachmentDetails(MediaRequestDetails mediaRequestObj,
            EntityManager entityManager) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Session session=(Session)entityManager.getDelegate();
        Transaction tx=session.beginTransaction();
        session.saveOrUpdate(mediaRequestObj);
        tx.commit();
        session.close();

    }

    private static MediaRequestDetails createMediaRequestDetails() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        MediaRequestDetails obj=new MediaRequestDetails();
        obj.setRequestorName("jinesh");
        obj.setRequestorType("MDA");
        return obj;
    }
    
    private static void createAttachmentDetails(MediaRequestDetails mediaRequDetails){
        Set<AttachmentDetails> attachmentDetailsSet=new HashSet<AttachmentDetails>();
        
        AttachmentDetails attachDetail=new AttachmentDetails();
        attachDetail.setAttachmentName("Test");
        attachDetail.setMediaRequDetails(mediaRequDetails);
        attachmentDetailsSet.add(attachDetail);
        mediaRequDetails.setAttachmentDetail(attachmentDetailsSet);
        
        
        
    }

}
```

When I am trying to execute the above class below is the error I am getting. I am not able to figure out what is the issue with the sequence because I don't see the sequence associated with the primary key of the AW_ATTACHMENT table getting called:

```
************* EntityManager is obtained *****************
Hibernate: select MEDIA_REQ_SEQ.nextval from dual
Hibernate: insert into AW_MEDIA_REQUEST (REQUESTOR_NAME, REQUESTOR_TYPE, ID) values (?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into AW_ATTACHMENT (ATTACHMENT_NAME, REQUEST_ID) values (?, ?)
Aug 26, 2015 7:34:13 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
WARN: SQL Error: 1400, SQLState: 23000
Aug 26, 2015 7:34:13 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("SCOTT"."AW_ATTACHMENT"."ATTACHMENT_ID")

Aug 26, 2015 7:34:13 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.AbstractBatchImpl release
INFO: HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:72)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:211)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:62)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3124)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3581)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:104)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:465)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:351)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:350)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:56)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1258)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:425)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.beforeTransactionCommit(JdbcTransaction.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:177)
    at com.sample.hb.jpa.onetomany.TestAttachmentSample.saveAttachmentDetails(TestAttachmentSample.java:49)
    at com.sample.hb.jpa.onetomany.TestAttachmentSample.main(TestAttachmentSample.java:36)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("SCOTT"."AW_ATTACHMENT"."ATTACHMENT_ID")

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:445)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:396)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:879)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:450)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:192)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:531)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:207)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForRows(T4CPreparedStatement.java:1044)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1329)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3584)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3665)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1352)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:208)
    ... 14 more
```

Comment: Is the attachment sequence in the "scott" schema?

Comment: @RedDeckWins Thanks for asking.yes Let me add the sequence DDL.

Comment: An EntityManager is present yet you use Hibernate API instead. #Weird

Comment: @Neil Could that be the issue ? I dont think it is.